# Generating .toc file without generating a ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc, shorttoc

**Problem**: I want to generate a `.toc` file without the table of contents actually being displayed anywhere in the text.

**Background**: I want a short ToC at the beginning of my text, using `shorttoc`. Then, using `titletoc`, I want a detailed in chapter ToC at the beginning of each chapter. For these detailed in chapter ToC's I need `\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}` in order to have the detailed information being written to the `.toc`. Now, `shorttoc` doesn't create a `.toc` file on its own but you have to place `\tableofcontents` somewhere after `\shorttoc`. So just leaving `\tableofcontents` out doesn't solve the problem.

**Possible solution**: Run (PDF)LaTeX first with `\tableofcontents` so that a `.toc` file is generated. Then comment it out and (PDF)LaTeX again.

That works of course but it is not at all an elegant way of solving the problem. I suppose there should be some way of creating `.toc` without actually creating a ToC with `\tableofcontents`.

Here is a MWE. It is not strictly speaking minimal, but the additional stuff shall make clear what the overall idea of the document is.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titletoc,titlesec}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\titlecontents{partsection}[2.3em]
{} {\contentslabel{2.3em}} {} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{partsubsection}[5.5em]
{} {\contentslabel{3.2em}} {} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{partsubsubsection}[9.6em]
{} {\contentslabel{4.1em}} {} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{partparagraph}[8.5em]
{} {\contentslabel{0em}} {} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
\lipsum[1]

\cleardoublepage

\shorttoc{Contents}{1}

\cleardoublepage

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{A chapter}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{part}{1}{}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{A second subsection}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection}
\paragraph{Paragraph}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Section 2}
\lipsum
\chapter{Second chapter}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{part}{1}{}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Another section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

**PS**: A solution which does not require major changes of the current configuration would be preffered (I mean I would rather not like to use different packages to get the overall output I get with the above code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another answer to my question: I actually do not need the `shorttoc` since by putting `\addtocontents{ptc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}}` into the last argument of `\printcontents` I can specify the depths for the partial ToC. So I can choose `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` for the normal ToC and nvertheless have deeper partial in chapter ToC's:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titletoc,titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\titlecontents{partsection}[2.3em]
{} {\contentslabel{2.3em}} {} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{partsubsection}[5.5em]
{} {\contentslabel{3.2em}} {} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{partsubsubsection}[9.6em]
{} {\contentslabel{4.1em}} {} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{partparagraph}[8.5em]
{} {\contentslabel{0em}} {} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
\lipsum[1]

\cleardoublepage

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{A chapter}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{part}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{A second subsection}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection}
\paragraph{Paragraph}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Section 2}
\lipsum
\chapter{Second chapter}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{part}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Another section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, now there are 4 more or less different solution ... difficult to say which is the most elegant one!? ;-)

Comment: Your solution is similiar to my one -- `\addtocontents` doesn't seem necessary, though.

Comment: David's and Heiko's answesr are great for situations where you want only partial ToCs. In case of a full ToC plus partial ToCs with higher depth, I'd prefer simply not to use the `shorttoc` package.

Answer (score 3):

`\tableofcontents` sets the chapter title and calls `\@starttoc{toc}`. The latter reads the contents file and starts a new one. The following redefines `\tableofcontents` that
only calls `\@starttoc{toc}` and the reading is disabled by locally redefining the
command for reading.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\tableofcontents}{%
  \begingroup
    \let\@input\@gobble
    \@starttoc{toc}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\makeatletter
      \newwrite\tf@toc
      \immediate\openout\tf@toc\jobname.toc\relax
\makeatother
```

is the bit of `\tableofcontents` that does not start a section and input the toc file.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `shorttoc` package, you could simply set the `tocdepth` counter to 1 at the start of the front matter (hereby affecting `\tableofcontents`), and to 4 at the start of the main matter.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titletoc,titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\titlecontents{partsection}[2.3em]
{} {\contentslabel{2.3em}} {} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{partsubsection}[5.5em]
{} {\contentslabel{3.2em}} {} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{partsubsubsection}[9.6em]
{} {\contentslabel{4.1em}} {} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{partparagraph}[8.5em]
{} {\contentslabel{0em}} {} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
\lipsum[1]

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\chapter{A chapter}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{part}{1}{}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{A second subsection}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection}
\paragraph{Paragraph}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Section 2}
\lipsum
\chapter{Second chapter}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{part}{1}{}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Another section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution (as well as mine) seems to be **incompatible** with `hyperref`. Could please try and load `hyperref` and give a feedback if you also get an error!? Thanks.

Comment: @lpdbw When adding the `hyperref` package (at the end of the preamble), you have to delete all auxiliary files before compiling again -- then it seems to work.