# ! File ended while scanning use of \@writefile

Tags: pdftex, compiling, compilation-error, write-file

I am getting below error when I am running the report to generate the PDF from GUI. I am using Texmaker 4.4.1. I also tried deleting aux files and other unwanted files. but, it is not helping me getting rid of this error.
Any ideas or workarounds to fix this ?

Thanks

> Excluding comment 'screenonly' Include comment 'printonly' Include
>   comment 'anonsuppress' (./sample-sigconf.aux) Runaway argument?
>   {\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {6.1}Default
>   Configuration}{4\ETC. ! File ended while scanning use of @writefile.
>
> \par l.61 \begin{document} I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing
>   me to read past where you wanted me to stop. I'll try to recover; but
>   if the error is serious, you'd better type`E' or `X' now and fix your
>   file. \openout1 =`sample-sigconf.aux'. LaTeX Font Info: Checking
>   defaults for OML/nxlmi/m/it on input line 61. LaTeX Font Info: Try
>   loading font information for OML+nxlmi on input line 61 .
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/omlnxlmi.fd File:
>   omlnxlmi.fd 2013/11/19 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OML/nxlmi.
>   )

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables

\settopmatter{printacmref=false}
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{} % removes footnote with conference information in first column
\pagestyle{plain} % removes running headers

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  breaklines=true,
  postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\color{red}$\hookrightarrow$\space}
}


% Copyright
%\setcopyright{none}
%\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
%\setcopyright{acmlicensed}
%\setcopyright{rightsretained}
%\setcopyright{usgov}
%\setcopyright{usgovmixed}
%\setcopyright{cagov}
%\setcopyright{cagovmixed}


% DOI
%\acmDOI{10.475/123_4}

% ISBN
%\acmISBN{123-4567-24-567/08/06}

%Conference
%\acmConference[WOODSTOCK'97]{ACM Woodstock conference}{July 1997}{El
 % Paso, Texas USA}
%\acmYear{1997}
%\copyrightyear{2016}


%\acmArticle{4}
%\acmPrice{15.00}

% These commands are optional
%\acmBooktitle{Transactions of the ACM Woodstock conference}
%\editor{Jennifer B. Sartor}
%\editor{Theo D'Hondt}
%\editor{Wolfgang De Meuter}


\begin{document}
\title{Data Storage Performance Collation}



\author{Apurva Jagdale}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{University of Passau}
}
\email{jagdal01@gw.uni-passau.de}


% The default list of authors is too long for headers.
%\renewcommand{\shortauthors}{B. Trovato et al.}


\begin{abstract}
``Data is the new oil!'' \cite{forbes:2018}

\end{abstract}

\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
<concept>
<concept_id>10002951.10002952.10003212.10003214</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Information systems~Database performance evaluation</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
<concept>
<concept_id>10011007.10010940.10011003.10011002</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Software and its engineering~Software performance</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>300</concept_significance>
</concept>
</ccs2012>
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{Information systems~Database performance evaluation}
\ccsdesc[300]{Software and its engineering~Software performance}

\keywords{NoSQL,Big Data,Streaming Data,Performance,Optimization}

\maketitle

\input{samplebody-conf_2}

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\newpage
\bibliography{sample_bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I do not get this error. (Of course, I commented out `\input{samplebody-conf_2}` and the bibliography related files, which I do not have.)

Comment: usually that error is caused by a corrupt aux file from an error in an earlier run, so first delete all aux and toc files associated with that document then check you have no fragile commands in \caption or \section etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @DavidCarlisle. Indeed it works when I comment the body file and bib file. I deleted aux file but I am not able to see .toc file .Any idea where it is located ?

Comment: unless you have a `\tableofcontents` to make a table of contents you won't have a toc file.

Comment: Yeah exactly I have added the code for toc file generation now. referred your comment from this 'https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66476/generating-toc-file-without-generating-a-toc' 
Now I started everthing but still the same. I am also attaching the log file getting generated during execution for your reference. There are some citation related warnings but those are not harmful. Link for the File https://ufile.io/tnsvx

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was wondering what the fragile commands are. I'm working on a chapter on KOMA Script book class where I'm putting some words inside an `\emph{}` command in the `\section` and `\subsection` headings. Everything was fine but with the latest one I get the same error (`TeX STOPPED: File ended while scanning use of \@writefil`) and I can't get rid of it. I have deleted the auxiliary files several times and the `.aux` is still generating with errors. I've removed the `\emph{}` from all the chapter headings and I still get the error. What could I do now to resolve this error?

Comment: @Aradnix asking questions as comments on old answer doesn't really work. In modern releases very few commands you would use in a section are fragile. But look at the aux file and see where the error is. It is writing a table of contents line and making an error so fix the matching \section  then delete .aux and .toc and re-run.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I felt it was better than asking a new question that would immediately be labelled as a duplicate and referred back to this one. Thank you for the explanation.